# Error trying to merge cells in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to filter a sheet in Excel, copy one column to a "middle sheet", copy each cell and paste it in a third sheet leaving 3 blank rows between each data, and then merge the cell with the data with the 3 blank ones after it.

The code works until it tries to merge the cells. It goes "crazy" and merge the entire A column. Does anyone see the error?

```
Sub Filtrar()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Lugar As String
Worksheets("Camiones_nacional").Activate
Lugar = Cells(2, 1).Value

Worksheets("Nacional_enero").Activate
Sheets("Nacional_enero").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Lugar

Range("A:A").Select
Selection.Copy

Worksheets("Calculos").Activate
Range("E1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Dim celda As Integer
celda = 1
Dim c As Integer
c = 2
Dim c1 As Integer
c1 = 5
Dim c2 As Integer
c2 = 8

Do While celda < 30
    Worksheets("Calculos").Activate
    Cells(c, 5).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Worksheets("Camiones_nacional").Activate
    Cells(c1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & c1 & ":" & "A" & c2).Merge

    celda = celda + 1
    c = c + 1
    c1 = c1 + 4
    c2 = c2 + 4
Loop

Worksheets("Camiones_nacional").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, flipping the selection can often trip up VBA, so its best to write your copy and paste in one line using the Destination property, or just reassign the values (as I will show here since your paste method had included only the values)

Further, in my experience, its best to use Cell calls in the Range rather than the Column concatnation

```
Do While celda < 30
    Worksheets("Camiones_nacional").Cells(c1, 1).Value = Worksheets("Calculos").Cells(c,5).Value

    Worksheets("Camiones_nacional").Range(Cells(c1,1),Cells(c2,1)).Merge

    celda = celda + 1
    c = c + 1
    c1 = c1 + 4
    c2 = c2 + 4
Loop
```

In reference to the entire column merging, I would debug by making sure that you are not inadvertently selecting a cell within an already merged range, as this will cause the merged ranges to combine

Comment: I changed your suggested code and now it works perfectly, however I don't know why mine didn't work, the "theory" says that it must work :P
Anyway, yours worked, so a lot of thanks.